# Sizing and Placing a UIView from xib in Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Forgive me if there is already an answer out there for this problem but I looked at them and wasn't sure about any of them.  Here is my problem:

I have a xib file, which has its own view (the superview).  On the superview, I have placed a Segmented Control at the top and a smaller UIView centered under the Segmented Control.  Using the Autosizing Control in the story board, I was able to make the view show up where I expected.  Now that I'm using a xib file in Xcode 4.3, I discovered that the Autosizing Control was not showing.  I fixed that and am able to now use the Autosizing Control.  However, I still cannot make the view show up where I expect.

Using Autolayout, at least my view was kind of where I want it.  Unchecking Autolayout and using the Autosizing Control, it looks like the superview (or whitespace) is now getting shoved to the upper left corner next to my Segmented Control.

I'm new to XCode and the new changes are really throwing a wrench in the mix for me.  Does anybody know how I can get my subview to display in the superview under my Segmented Control?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I've learned!  You really do NOT want to uncheck Autolayout.  Instead keep Autolayout and learn how to deal with the new constraints.  MUCH easier; MUCH better.  Just become a constraints guru and the new Autolayout (default) handles everything for you (including auto rotate).  SLICK BEYOND BELIEF!!!!